# Entity Framework Core 2.2 Child Table Lookup is Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have an Entity Framework Core 2.2 model with a master and child tables. All tables have a one to one relationship. Both the Master and Child tables have fields that link to the same lookup table. The link for the master table works as expected with MainTable.NameLookup showing all the fields and data. The link to the child table results in a null result even with Include/ThenInclude. So ChildTable.NameLookup exists but is null. I hope I'm presenting this clearly. Here is the pseudo code of what I'm doing.

So is what I'm try to do available within the framework and if so what am I missing?

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<MainTable> MainTable { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ChildTable> ChildTable { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<NameLookup> NameLookup{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MainTable>()
            .HasOne(w => w.NameLookup)
            .WithOne(p => p.MainTable)
            .HasPrincipalKey<MainTable>(d => d.NameCode1)
            .HasForeignKey<NameLookup>(p => p.NameCode)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildTable>()
            .HasOne(w => w.NameLookup)
            .WithOne(p => p.ChildTable)
            .HasPrincipalKey<ChildTable>(d => d.NameCode2)
            .HasForeignKey<NameLookup>(p => p.NameCode)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildTable>()
            .HasOne(d => d.FileNumberNavigation)
            .WithOne(p => p.ChildTable)
            .HasForeignKey<ChildTable>(d => d.FileNumber);
    }
}

public class MainTable
{
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }
    public string NameCode1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ChildTable ChildTable { get; set; }
    public virtual NameLookup NameLookup { get; set; }
}

public class ChildTable
{
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }
    public string NameCode2 { get; set; }

    public virtual MainTable FileNumberNavigation { get; set; } 
    public virtual NameLookup NameLookup { get; set; }
}

public class NameLookup
{
    public string NameCode { get; set; }
    public string MoreInfo { get; set; }

    public virtual ChildTable ChildTable { get; set; }
    public virtual MainTable MainTable { get; set; }

}
```

This is for a winforms application. Within the application I retrieve the MainTable dbSet with the following snippet:

```
        private readonly DbSet<MainTable > dbSetEntity;
        public MainTableRepository(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
            base.dbContext = dbContext;
            dbSetEntity = dbContext.Set<MainTable >();
        }

        public MainTable GetMainTable(string FileNumber )
        {
            return dbSetEntity
                .Include(t => t.ChildTable)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.NameLookup)
                .SingleOrDefault(a => a.FileNumber == FileNumber);
        }

        public string GetMoreInfo (string FileNumber)
        {
            var q = from e in dbSetEntity
                where e.FileNumber == FileNumber
                select e.ChildTable.NameLookup.MoreInfo ;
            return q.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Calling GetMainTable returns the MainTable fields and data and it also contains the MainTable.ChildTable fields and data. However MainTable.ChildTable.NameLookup is null.

If I call GetMoreInfo it does return the field data from the NameLookup.MoreInfo field.

Comment: Where is your query that you are trying?

Comment: Added the queries to the question. Thx